# OSM - the best way to parse way maxspeed way tag

Tags: java, openstreetmap

I encountered a problem while parsing `maxspeed` way tag. It's unexpectedly complex tag. Just see how complex it gets here [http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Key:maxspeed](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Key%3amaxspeed). There are a couple regex in the end of the article. That's good and helpful albeit incomplete. However I am concerned about regex performance considering number of ways and tags. Apart from regex, what are my options?

PS: yes, I rephrased my question to make off-topic cops/maniacs happy.

Answer (score 0):

How about looking at how others parse this tag? The OSM wiki as a long list of [online routers](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Routing/OnlineRouters) and [offline routers](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Routing/offline_routers) of which many are open source. But I assume most software currently uses only the regular *maxspeed* tag and maybe *maxspeed:forward* and *maxspeed:backward*.